# Prevent image transparent inside a transparent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

you can see my problem on this image :

[image]

as you can see, the div is transparent and it effected the img es inside it .
this is my html code:

```
<div id="cselect" style="position: absolute; top: 99px; left: 37px; display: block;">
    <div class="cnvptr">
        <img src="uploadfabrics/14606171783156.jpg" >
    </div>
    <div class="cnvptr">
        <img src="uploadfabrics/16292373497271.jpg" ></div>
    </div>
```

these are css codes:

```
#cselect {
    padding: 15px;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 2%;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: relative;
}
.cnvptr {
    background: black;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I put a div around each image with class `cnvptr`, it has black background but It doesn't work .

How can I make image backgrounds not transparent?

Thanks

Comment: Remove the `opacity: 0.5` ...?

Comment: Could you put this in a codepen/fiddle so we can easily see and test your problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use rgba instead:

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

```css
#cselect {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 2%;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.cnvptr {
  background: black;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="cselect" style="position: absolute; top: 99px; left: 37px; display: block;">
  <div class="cnvptr">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" />
  </div>
  <div class="cnvptr">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Same code using opacity instead:

```css
#cselect {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 2%;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  /*background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);*/
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.cnvptr {
  background: black;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="cselect" style="position: absolute; top: 99px; left: 37px; display: block;">
  <div class="cnvptr">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" />
  </div>
  <div class="cnvptr">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use rgba background colour instead, and don't change the opacity of the div.

```
 #cselect {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    opacity:1;
 }
```

Comment: What's the difference with my answer?

Comment: Your answer hadn't been posted when I answered :P

Comment: Is one minute later but is ok then ;)

Answer (score 1):

Note that `rgba(0,0,0,.5);` will have compatibility issues.

Check [RGBa Browser Support](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/).

**Another solution can be:**
In your case this will not work, you have to change your `HTML` structure i.e. Keep your inner div's out of `id="cselect"`.

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
    <h2>Hello World!</h2>
    <div class=”tp-bg”></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tp-bg
{
    background: #000;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Here is another blog on fixing [CSS Opacity issue on child div](http://aamirshahzad.net/css-opacity-issue-on-child-divs/).